# Check Resize Only On Completion

Tags: jquery, events, listener, responsive-design

In developing a navigation menu with very specific design details, I am using this to check the window size and append some code after selected elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
var $window = $(window);

function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize >= 768) {
        //if the window is greater than 440px wide then turn on jScrollPane..
        $('nav.dropdowns ul.patient>li:nth-child(4n+5)').after('<div class="clear"></div>');
    }
    else if (windowsize <= 767) {
        //if the window is greater than 440px wide then turn on jScrollPane..
        $('nav.dropdowns ul.patient>li:nth-child(3n+4)').after('<div class="clear"></div>');
    }
}
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

The problem is that it keeps firing, which appends my code endlessly. I can easily solve this by removing the event listener. This works great is a window is loaded as it's final size. But in terms of fluid responsiveness, it fails as the event only first on load and not anytime after that. I have looked at a thousand other scripts, but have found no way to prevent the event from firing over and over again that I can actually get working.

Comment: Have you tried using CSS media queries to accomplish this? Responsive design generally happens there.

Comment: I was going to point out that we support IE7/8 thusly jQuery would be needed in place of CSS selectors...but I just found Selectivizr.js

Comment: I don't know of many mobile devices that are using IE7/8. Are you sure you need it to be responsive?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is not to fire the function excessively, you can use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.  Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);

    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize >= 768) {
            //if the window is greater than 440px wide then turn on jScrollPane..
            $('nav.dropdowns ul.patient>li:nth-child(4n+5)').after('<div class="clear"></div>');
        }
        else if (windowsize <= 767) {
            //if the window is greater than 440px wide then turn on jScrollPane..
            $('nav.dropdowns ul.patient>li:nth-child(3n+4)').after('<div class="clear"></div>');
        }
    }

    var timeoutId;
    function resizeEvent(){
        // 'reset' the timeout each fire
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        // save reference to the timeout delay in 'timeoutId'.  10ms delay
        timeoutId = setTimeout(checkWidth, 10);
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(resizeEvent);
});
```

This will fire `resizeEvent()` constantly, but the 10ms delay will prevent `checkWidth()` from running constantly.

**NOTE:** This is a solution to your problem, but may not be the best solution.  You should look into achieving as much as you can in just `CSS`